# namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl

Tags: php, macos, laravel, xampp, jwt

I'm trying to composer update but it said:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.1 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.2 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.3 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.0 requires namshi/jose 2.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.9 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.4 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.5 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.6 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.7 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.8 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.9 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1].
    - namshi/jose 2.2.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.3 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.* -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.5, 0.5.6, 0.5.7, 0.5.8, 0.5.9].
```

I was try to search over the internet but still can't fix, I'm using XAMPP running with macOS Sierra and I already tried too:

```
php -i | grep "SSL Version"
SSL Version => SecureTransport
rm /usr/local/bin/openssl
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local
```

But it still

```
php -i | grep "SSL Version"
SSL Version => SecureTransport
```

Another options I tried:

```
brew link openssl --force Warning: Refusing to link: openssl Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure, deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl. Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

I checked my OpenSSL version:

```
openssl OpenSSL> version OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016
```

And tried also with this:

```
    ls -lash /usr/local/bin/openssl 8 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root admin 44B Oct 20 01:18 /usr/local/bin/openssl -> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl and ls -lash /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl 1064 -r-xr-xr-x 1 aryo admin 528K Oct 19 17:38 /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl ln: /usr/local/bin/openssl: File exists
```

Comment: you might need `openssl-devel`

Comment: I'm not sure tbh - it looks like things are in a bit of a mess. It looks like you have more than one version installed but the paths or links might be broken/wrong - this is beyond me sorry. This link might be of help; http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x

Comment: have a look at that file - is it a 'real' file or a (dead) link?

Comment: `ls -lash /usr/local/bin/openssl` and `ls -lash /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl` should show you both

Comment: by the looks of it `/usr/local/bin/openssl` is already linked to `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl`

Comment: Sorry no idea :( You might want to edit your question with the stuff we have gone through in these comments so its easier for someone else to look at it and not have to dig through all these. If you do please feel free to drop me a mesg & delete the redundant comments & I'll do the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl on macosx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417725/namshi-jose-5-0-2-requires-lib-openssl-on-macosx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MacOS Sierra uses a "Native OpenSSL" implementation that is not correctly detected by composer. You can verify it by executing the following command line:

```
php -i | grep OpenSSL
```

If you see `LibreSSL` then try to recompile OpenSSL using Homebrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/php
brew install curl --with-libssh2 --with-openssl
```

Now your OpenSSL implementation should be `OpenSSL` and the installation of `namshi/jose` should work fine. You can see a discussion about this topic [on my Jose project](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose/issues/148).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with macOS Sierra. The exact same thing happened to me. I upgraded to Sierra, and then my entire development environment broke with similar errors. I had to downgrade to El Capitan.