# namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl on macosx

Tags: macos, xampp, jwt

I looked at other questions, but I could not find a solution.While trying to install [JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package I get an error as mentioned in the title.

I am using xampp version 7.0.8 on mac os x Sierra with PHP 5.6.The error I get is as follows.

```
Problem 1
    - namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.9 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth ^0.5.9 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.9].
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone who uses [the Jose library I developed](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose) had encountered the same problem. You can see the issue he opened [on this page](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose/issues/148).

The problem is that on MacOS Sierra the OpenSSL implementation is not correctly detected by composer and if a library needs `lib-openssl` then this message appears.

You can verify your OpenSSL implementation by executing the following command line:

```
php -i | grep OpenSSL
```

If you see `LibreSSL` then try to change it:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/php
brew install curl --with-libssh2 --with-openssl
```

Now your OpenSSL implementation should be `OpenSSL` and the installation of `namshi/jose` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it after I installed mamp and it worked.