# Laravel Composer require issue with Mac Sierra

Tags: php, macos, laravel, openssl, composer-php

I'm trying to include [Laravel 5 Facade for Goutte](https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte) in my application. However I am getting the following error:

```
 Problem 1
- namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
- namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
- namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
- Installation request for namshi/jose (locked at 5.0.2) -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.2].
```

I have searched online and it suggests installing a new version of PHP and try using that instead however I have installed php56 via homebrew and its still not working. When i run:

```
which php
```

it says the path is:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

However brew installed PHP to:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/bin
```

I have updated my .bash_profile with the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/bin
```

However even after restarting the terminal which php still returns /usr/bin/php.

Comment: Did you try to enable lib-openssl for your php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires lib-openssl on macosx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417725/namshi-jose-5-0-2-requires-lib-openssl-on-macosx)

Comment: Ive tried the answer in that question and it doesnt work

Comment: Yes I have tried enabling lib-openssl still doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried to run composer with the 'new' php ? Try this command `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/bin/php composer require weidner/goutte`

Comment: It says: Could not open input file: composer when i try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a symlink for new php version this way :

```
sudo ln /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.30_6/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

Then run your composer command

```
php composer require weidner/goutte
```

or

```
php composer.phar require weidner/goutte
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Works great thanks for the answer. Im still a bit confused as to why I cant change the php version using .bash_profile but this gets around that issue. Thanks.